# Return a sequence of elements in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I want to return a sequence of Cards in a game in Haskell. For example:

```
[(SIX,D),(SEVEN,D),(EIGHT,S)] ~> [(SIX,D),(SEVEN,D)] 
[(SIX,D),(SEVEN,S)] ~> []
[(SIX,D),(SEVEN,D)] ~> [(SIX,D),(SEVEN,D)]
```

Until now, I have this function:

```
findSeq :: [Card] -> [Card]
findSeq [] = []
findSeq (h:t)
    | null t = [h]
    | Just h == (pCard (head t) pack) = h:findSeq t
    | otherwise = [h]
```

Which returns even the first card: i.e, unsuitable for example 2 above. How can I return a sequence, or nothing else if there is no sequence of consecutive elements in there?

I also tried filtering them, but I received 'too many arguments exception'. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```hs
import Data.List (groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)

data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving Eq
data Face = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King deriving Enum

type Card = (Face, Suit)

findSequences :: [Card] -> [[Card]]
findSequences = [sequence | sequence <- groupBy ((==) `on` snd),
                            contiguous (map fst sequence),
                            length sequence > 1]

contiguous :: Enum a => [a] -> Bool
contiguous (x:xs) = map fromEnum xs == take (length xs) [fromEnum x + 1 ..]
```

The `findSequences` function finds all the sequences in the deck (except single card sequences).

Answer (score 1):

Well, mathematically it actually makes perfect sense to consider a single card a sequence of one card. So it's a good idea to not change that behaviour as such... just extend the definition so you can obtain the real desired result from that.

The real problem is not that you get single cards as single-element sequences, but *that you don't get anything behind them*. To fix that, you need to first obtain not merely the first, but *all* sequences in the list:

```
findSeqs :: [Card] -> [[Card]]
findSeqs [] = []
findSeqs [h] = [[h]]
findSeqs (h:t@(h':_))  -- avoid `head` and `null`... pattern matching FTW!
  | Just h == (pCard h' pack)  = h ^: findSeqs t
  | otherwise                  = [h] : findSeqs t
```

I've used the helper

```
(^:) :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
h ^: (hl:ls) = (h:hl) : ls
_ ^: [] = []
```

Once you have `findSeqs`, you merely need to skim the result for the first non-degenerate sequence.